# How do I manually delete an instance of a class?

Tags: c++, class, instance, destructor, kill

How do I manually delete an instance of a class?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Cheese {
private:
    string brand;
    float cost;
public:
    Cheese(); // Default constructor
    Cheese(string brand, float cost); // Parametrized constructor
    Cheese(const Cheese & rhs); // Copy construtor
    ~Cheese(); // Destructor
    // etc... other useful stuff follows
}

int main() {
    Cheese cheddar("Cabot Clothbound", 8.99);
    Cheese swiss("Jarlsberg", 4.99);

    whack swiss; 
    // fairly certain that "whack" is not a keyword,
    // but I am trying to make a point. Trash this instance!

    Cheese swiss("Gruyère",5.99);
    // re-instantiate swiss

    cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is "Cabot Clothbound" Cheddar cheese - Comes from nowhere near [Cheddar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheddar,_Somerset)

Comment: A variable (instance of a class) declared on the stack can have its memory set to zero with ``memset`` (which would be useful in some cases I guess...), but its memory cannot be released until the end of the function scope you declared it in (until the end of your main here). You can just overwrite your variable content with the copy constructor if you really want to stay on the stack, but why do you not use the heap and pointers in this case where you can ``delete`` your instance?

Comment: @Ed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheddar_cheese

Comment: @EdHeal: It's not like champagne. It's not a protected term. The name refers to the recipe that originated at Cheddar. A bit like the million "American" grey squirrels whose parents and grandparents even have never heard of America let alone set paw there!

Comment: I know - unfortunately - but the English stuff from Cheddar is the best. Also champagne is another English invention.Missed out again :-(

Comment: Just make sure the cheese is fresh. You wouldn't want to wait until it's gone "off".

Comment: What brand from Cheddar?

Answer (score 12):

Without knowing the use-case or the actual problem you want to solve (please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), your question is a good example of it) the simplest way is just reassigning:

```
Cheese swiss("Jarlsberg", 4.99);
...
swiss = Cheese("Gruyère",5.99);
```

That might of course require you to implement an assignment operator, but following the [rules of three or five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) you should do that anyway (but the assignment operator is not needed if you follow [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero)).

You *could* also use pointers, if you explicitly want to destroy the current `swiss` object:

```
Cheese* swiss = new Cheese("Jarlsberg", 4.99);
...
delete swiss;
swiss = new Cheese("Gruyère",5.99);
```

But pointers is a can of worms that you should avoid, and don't really need much in modern C++. But pointers (or references) are needed if you want polymorphism. Then you could have a pointer to the base class pointing to the actual instance, and things like virtual functions will work as expected.

Also, and depending on your situation which we still know nothing about, you could of course use scoping:

```
Cheese swiss("Jarlsberg", 4.99);
...
{
    Cheese swiss("Gruyère",5.99);
    // In here the swiss cheese is a Gruyère
    ...
}
// Out here the swiss cheese is a Jarlsberg
```

Though shadowing variable names like this works, it's a bad habit that you should avoid as it adds confusion for readers of the code. On the other hand, even when using scopes nothing stops you from using any (valid) variable name you want, so you could name the outer scope instance `jarlsberg` and the inner scope instance `gruyere`, the `gruyere` object would then be destructed at the end of the scope just like any other nested-scope variable would be destructed and "disappear".

Comment: The name shadowing is a bad idea, yes, but you could make it clearer that the general technique of using braces to control scope is by far the _best_ of the three shown techniques.

Comment: Separate scopes would be the best, but I would promote sequential scopes, not nested scopes: `{ Cheese swiss(1); } ... { Cheese swiss(2); }`

Comment: Helpful suggestions, thank you. Am I to thus conclude that this functionality does not exist in the language, as stated in the OP? That is: ``whack swiss;``

Answer (score 5):

One can use scoping to allow you to define another instance of a class.

```
Cheese swiss("Toe", 3.14)

{
    Cheese swiss("Ear", 15.9);
}
```

As a general rule locally declared instances will destroy themselves when they go out of scope.

If you really feed the need to destroy cheese, then you need to dynamically allocate it instead.

```
  Cheese *swiss = new Cheese("toe", 3);

   // do something with swiss.

   delete swiss;    // throw it away.

   swiss = new Cheese("Ear", 7);

   // do something with swiss.

   delete swiss;    // throw it away.
```

Dynamically allocated memory must always be manually deleted.

Comment: _"As a general rule"_ Read: absolutely always, with no exceptions. That's what going out of scope means.

Comment: _"Dynamically allocated memory must always be manually deleted"_ That was true twenty years ago, but now that you should be using smart pointers it's essentially _never_ true in good code.

Comment: I love your nick.   I agree with you.  The issue is that the op is new or he wouldn't be asking a question like this.   The answer strives to point him to two things he needs to know about.   the answer is already complex enough without adding the concept of smart pointers, or of the exception handling needed to correctly deal with that code.

Comment: If the OP is new then it's even more important not to misteach them, as they will not know the difference. Besides, smart pointers are the _easy_ approach that we should start with; leave the advanced topics like manual memory management for when the OP has a bit more experience.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should answer the question.

Comment: I don't see why. The possible solutions have been broadly covered across the existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are precious few instances where you would need to do this.  But one that you might run into is when creating an abstract data type.

For instance, if you're making a variant type you'll probably want to set up an aligned data type and then manually placement new and delete.

```
typename std::aligned_union<0, FirstType, RestTypes...>::type m_buffer;
```

To vivify:

```
new (&m_buffer) AssignType(forward<T>(x));
```

To clear:

```
(HeldType*)(&m_buffer)->~HeldType();
```

However, as mentioned in the numerous other posts.  If you're programming normally, then you don't need to worry about manually calling dtors.  If it's on the stack then it's cleaned up for you.  If it's on the heap then `delete` will take care of it for you.  The only time where you want to do this is where you're manually taking control over object lifetimes, and the main reason why you'd want to do this is when you're implementing an abstract data type.

Comment: Good answer except for the "stack"/"heap" gubbins

Comment: Is there a nomenclature that's preferred?

Answer (score 1):

A general Rule 
Locally created Instances are automatically deleted/taken care once it goes out of scope.
Dynamically created Instances (Dynamic Memory Allocation) need to be deleted manually as follows:

**delete instance_name;**

- *Note*
  : Do not include delete instance_name statement inside ~cheese() (~destructor), otherwise it will enter into a loop and crash

In above case where you manually want to delete the instance, it is recommended use DMA:

```
int main() {
    Cheese cheddar("Cabot Clothbound", 8.99);
    Cheese* swiss = new swiss("Jarlsberg", 4.99);

    delete swiss;


    Cheese swiss("Gruyère",5.99);
    // re-instantiate swiss

    cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dark Side of C++ posesses a technique for performing exactly what you describe in the original post.  I don't know why you want to do this -- maybe implementing an assignment operator seems tedious.  Maybe you have a morbid desire to do something unnatural to your program.  I can assure you that no "normal" person would consider using the code I reveal below, at least not when others are watching.  So why am I putting this here?

Because I'm sadistic.

I call upon the power of Community Wiki to shield me from the onslaught!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <new>

template <typename T, typename ...As>
inline void Reconstruct(T &ojt, const As&... ctor_args) {
    // Explicitly call the destructor, to destroy the object
    // without doing anything to its memory allocation.
    ojt.~T();

    // Use Placement new to call a constructor.
    // Instead of allocating memory somewhere for a new object,
    // this specifies where the new object will be constructed --
    // given here as the location of the object's previous
    // incarnation.
    // Also pass any arguments to the constructor.  I forced
    // these arguments to be const references in order to
    // avoid extra copying, so "move" construction won't work
    // and steps might need to be taken to accommodate other,
    // more unusual constructors.
    new(&ojt) T(ctor_args...);
}

class Cheese {
    std::string brand;
    float       cost;
public:
    Cheese() : cost(0) {}
    Cheese(std::string brand, float cost) : brand(brand), cost(cost) {}
    Cheese(const Cheese & rhs) = default;
    ~Cheese() = default;
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Cheese& chz) {
        return os << "[brand:\"" << chz.brand << "\" cost:" << chz.cost << ']';
    }
};

int main() {
    Cheese cheese, fromage;
    std::cout << "cheese = " << cheese << '\n';

    Reconstruct(cheese, "Cabot Clothbound", 8.99f);
    std::cout << "cheese = " << cheese << '\n';

    Reconstruct(fromage, cheese);
    std::cout << "fromage = " << fromage << '\n';

    Reconstruct(cheese, "Jarlsberg", 4.99f);
    std::cout << "cheese = " << cheese << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you can not use the assignment operator, you can use an `optional`.

```
std::experimental::optional<Cheese> swiss(std::experimental::in_place, "Jarlsberg", 4.99);

swiss = std::experimental::nullopt; // Calls Cheese::~Cheese internally

// re-instantiate swiss
swiss.emplace("Gruyère",5.99);
```

As long as you are not storing the optional, you can probably rely on the compiler optimizing out the extra internal bool.