# How to reset number of instances of a class to 1 on every loop iteration?

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

I have a `player` class where I am storing the player's current position, the number of players in the game and a static variable to store the total number of players like so:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using std::time;
using std::cout;

class Player
{
private:
    int m_Player_currentPosition, m_Player_number;
    static int m_Player_numberOfPlayers;
public:
    Player::Player():m_Player_currentPosition(1) {
        m_Player_number = m_Player_numberOfPlayers;
        ++m_Player_numberOfPlayers;
    }
    void m_Player_SetPosition();
    int m_Player_GetPosition();
    int m_Player_GetPlayerNumber() { return m_Player_number; }
    void m_Player_SetNumberOfPlayers() { m_Player_numberOfPlayers = 1; }
    ~Player() { --m_Player_numberOfPlayers; }
};

int Player::m_Player_numberOfPlayers = 1;

#endif
```

I also have a `game` class that creates a certain number of player instances using a vector. In my game class, the plan is to create players depending on user input (between 2-4 number of players) using `m_Game_SetPlayers()` member function and also printing the details of the players using the `m_Game_PrintPlayers()` member function.

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"
#include "Player.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;

class Game {
private:
    bool m_Game_quit;
    int m_Game_choice;
    Board board;
    vector<Player> m_Game_players;
public:
    Game();

    const bool &m_Game_GetQuit() const;

    void m_Game_SetPlayers()
    {
        int numberOfPlayers = 2;
        cout << "How many players (2-4)? ";
        cin >> numberOfPlayers;
        if (numberOfPlayers < 2 || numberOfPlayers > 4) {
            numberOfPlayers = 2;
        }
        m_Game_players.resize(numberOfPlayers);
    }
    void m_Game_PrintMenu();
    void m_Game_PrintInstructions();
    void m_Game_GetChoice();
    void m_Game_PrintPlayers()
    {
        cout << '\n';
        vector<Player>::iterator iter;
        for (iter = m_Game_players.begin(); iter != m_Game_players.end(); ++ iter) {
            cout << "Player " << iter->m_Player_GetPlayerNumber() << "'s position: " << iter- 
            >m_Player_GetPosition() << '\n';
        }
    }

    void Update();
};

#endif // !GAME_H
```

However, in my `main` class, I am calling the Game class's update function under a `while` loop. Here is my game update member function declared in a separate implementation file that decides the control flow of the game.

```
void Game::Update()
{
    m_Game_GetChoice();
    switch (m_Game_choice) {
    case 0: cout << "---Bye---\n";
        m_Game_quit = true;
        break;
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        m_Game_PrintInstructions();
        break;
    case 2:
        system("cls");
        m_Game_SetPlayers();
        system("cls");
        board.m_Board_PrintBoard();
        m_Game_PrintPlayers();
        m_Game_players[0].m_Player_SetNumberOfPlayers();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "--Invalid Option---\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is my `while` loop in the main function:

```
#include "Game.h"

int main() {
    Game game;

    while (!game.m_Game_GetQuit()) {
        system("cls");
        game.m_Game_PrintMenu();
        game.Update();
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

When I ran this program the first time, it worked as expected. However, imagine if I choose the `play` option from the menu and I enter 2 players, it creates 2 instances of the player class. On the next while loop iteration, I increase the size to 4 players which also works perfectly sometimes. Then, when I reduce the size and then again increase the size, the player number does not match. Here are the following images to help understand the problem:

- Input 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/reHjE.png
- Output 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt68V.png
- Input 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo83c.png
- Output 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qso6.png 
  The expected output is:
- Player's position 1: 1
- Player's position 2: 1
- Player's position 3: 1 
  So, I thought that I need to delete my instances, but since I cannot delete instances on a stack memory as long as I am in a while loop ([How do I manually delete an instance of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192499/how-do-i-manually-delete-an-instance-of-a-class), http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/107822/). I thought that I will resize the vector. It did resize the vector, but then it does not delete the instances of the `player` class but instead created a new instance of that class. Is there a way to destroy all the instances of the class on a stack memory even when it is inside the scope? If not, how do I solve this problem? 
  I may/may not have provided the code needed to debug this problem. So, I have attached my entire code on https://github.com/F3INTH34RTED/Cpp/tree/master/Beginner/16SnakesAndLadder if need be.

Comment: `int Player::m_Player_numberOfPlayers = 1;` should be `int Player::m_Player_numberOfPlayers = 0;` You don't have any players until you've instantiated the first `Player`.

Comment: In my player constructor, I am first initializing it to the player number value, and then iterating the static data member. That is why I have initialized it to 1.

Comment: When I set ```Player::m_Player_numberOfPlayers = 0;``` it is acting different;y. If I enter '3' players the second time, it first prints ```player's 1 position``` then it just prints ```player 2's position``` for the remaining iterations

Comment: Then since `m_Player_numberOfPlayers` doesn't count how many players there are, consider renaming it - or better, keep the name but increase the value before assigning: `Player() : m_Player_number(++m_Player_numberOfPlayers) {}`.

Comment: Should a `Player` be copyable? If it should, should the copy get a new player number?

Comment: No, a player cannot be copyable. It is a snakes and ladders game. It does not make sense to me to make it copyable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you increase the size of the vector, say from 2 to 3, it only needs to create one new instance of `Player`, so it will create a single player with the next number.

The line

```cpp
m_Game_players[0].m_Player_SetNumberOfPlayers();
```

on the previous loop iteration sets the global counter to 1. So this single new player gets number 1, not number 3 like you expect. You should be able to remove the above line and things will work as expected.

On a design note, it would probably be wiser to recreate the vector entirely when the number of players is changed and explicitly give each player a number via the constructor, like this:

```cpp
void m_Game_SetPlayers()
    {
        int numberOfPlayers = 2;
        cout << "How many players (2-4)? ";
        cin >> numberOfPlayers;
        if (numberOfPlayers < 2 || numberOfPlayers > 4) {
            numberOfPlayers = 2;
        }
        m_Game_players.clear();
        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
            m_Game_players.push_back(Player(i));
        }
    }
```

Updating the `Player` constructor to match, of course.

Comment: By removing this line: ```m_Game_players[0].m_Player_SetNumberOfPlayers();``` the first time it works fine, but then on the second iteration, when I increase the size from 3 to 4 this is what happens:
```player 1's position: 1```
```player 2's position: 1```
```player 3's position: 1```
```player 3's position: 1```

Comment: However, the command ```m_Game_player.clear();``` worked perfectly! Thank you Good Sir!

Comment: @ProgrammingRage You don't need to `clear()` to keep the player numbers in check. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rEbh9z)

Comment: @ProgrammingRage What's the implementation of `m_Player_GetPosition`? I can't find it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `std::vector::push_back` will do copy/move when it needs to resize internal buffer, and your (auto generated default) copy/move constructors doesn't handle that, you might do for example:

```
class Player
{
private:
    int m_currentPosition;
    std::optional<int> m_number;
    static int m_numberOfPlayers;
public:
    Player() : m_currentPosition(1), m_number(++m_numberOfPlayer) {}
    Player(const Player&) = delete;
    Player(Player&& rhs) : m_currentPosition(rhs.m_currentPosition), m_number(rhs.m_number) { rhs.m_number = std::nullopt; }
    Player& operator = (const Player&) = delete;
    Player& operator = (Player&& rhs) { std::swap(m_currentPosition, rhs.m_currentPosition); std::swap(m_number, rhs.m_number); }

    int GetPlayerNumber() const { return *m_number; }
    ~Player() { if (m_number) --m_numberOfPlayers; }
};
```